# Doctrine2 returns returns fields with wrong data type

Tags: symfony, types, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a mid-size Symfony2 project. While using several doctrine entities I stucked on the following "error".

I've got an entity with 3 fields:

```xml
<entity name="xxx\yyyBundle\Entity\ABTexte" table="ABTexte">
    <id name="Nr" type="integer" />
    <field name="OID" type="integer" />
    <field name="Text" type="string" />
    <many-to-one target-entity="xxx\yyyBundle\Entity\ABKopf" field="ABKopf" inversed-by="ABTexte">
        <join-column name="OID" referenced-column-name="OID" on-delete="CASCADE" />
    </many-to-one>
</entity>
```

After loading one or more entities using $repo->findBy() I receive an entities with wrong datatypes. My result is:

```
$ABKopf->Nr (int)
$ABKopf->Text (string)
$ABKopf->OID (string)     <===== !!!!!!!!!
```

It's very important for my application to get this value as an integer. Do you have any ideas what causes this behaviour?

PS: All values are filled with data of the correct data type. e. g. OID = 999000

### I verified that, when I use an integer column as a foreign key (many-to-one relationship...) doctrine always returns it as a string

Relationship in ABKopf:

```xml
<entity name="xxx\yyyBundle\Entity\ABKopf" table="ABKopf">
    <id name="OID" column="OID" type="integer" />
    <field name="ABNr" column="ABNr" type="integer" />
    <!-- ... -->
    <one-to-many target-entity="xxx\yyyBundle\Entity\ABTexte" field="ABTexte" mapped-by="ABKopf" />
</entity>
```

ABTexte-Entity: https://gist.github.com/715f3881a57cdd8a7d23

Comment: Did you create the table with doctrine or did you map an existing table? What datatype is the OID-column in your table?

Comment: @mahok I created the table using doctrine. The datatypes of the fields in my datatable are corresponding to the doctrine-XML: OID int(11), Nr int(11), Text varchar(255).
When var_dumping the entity after a call of $repo->findBy(), $entity->Nr is correctly dumped as an integer, OID is dumped as a string...

Comment: PS: At first I didn't define a datatype for column OID so it was a varchar(255) / string. Later I changed the datatype to integer, and used doctrine:generate:schema command to update the column in the database...

Comment: PPS: Even after deleting and recreating the datatable there's the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

> PS: At first I didn't define a datatype for column OID so it was a
> varchar(255) / string. Later I changed the datatype to integer, and
> used doctrine:generate:schema command to update the column in the
> database...

I'll explain you the entire "doctrine process" for generate entities.

At first you write a PHP class with some annotation or a yml,xml,ecc that tells doctrine how to create entities, link each other, and so on.

Second step is about generating getters and setter in an automated way `doctrine:generate:entities`

### IMPORTANT

The third step is, when you want to change something about your schema, use the following command `doctrine:schema:update --force`

### END IMPORTANT

I suppose that `doctrine:generate:schema` doesn't do what you're expecting that it to do.

Try with command that I've wrote on the third step

Comment: Thx for your answer. 

I know that I have to use the force-Flag to write the schema changes into DB. I've done it. And I checked the settings in my DB, so I'm sure that the database-tables have the same type settings as my doctrine-definitions.

**I've tried removing the foreign-key (many-to-one-relationship) from my entity, and then findBy returns the values with the correct data-types. After re-enabling the foreign-key, OID is returned as a string again.**

Comment: @RenePöpperl this is kind of strange because keys have to be of the same type. Have you checked at the other side of your association for understand what's goin' on?

Comment: I've tried some approaches:

    `$ABKopf = $repoABKopf->findOneBy(...);`
    `$OID    = $ABKopf->getABTexte()[0]->getOID();`

Here I get OID as integer. If I call

    `$ABTexte = $repoABTexte->findBy(...);`
    `$OID = $ABTexte[0]->getOID();`

... I receive a string. From this point on, even if I call

    `$ABKopf->getABTexte()[0]->getOID();`

I receive a string...

In each table OID is used, datatype is integer.

Comment: @RenePöpperl looks strange

Comment: I verified that, when I use an integer column as a foreign key (many-to-one relationship...) doctrine always returns it as a string... but I need an integer... :-(

Comment: @RenePöpperl could you provide the section of code where you define that relationship? Please, update your question